# Unable to proceed with the Azure Open AI Chat Deployment

Tags: .net, azure, openai-api, azure-openai

I am trying to do the deployment through my data source where the files are been stored in my blob storage, but when I execute it it's just getting stuck at the ingestion phase and after that, it gives me the below error:

> Could not execute skill because it did not execute within the time
> limit '00:01:00'. This is likely transient. Please try again later.
> For custom skills, consider increasing the 'timeout' parameter on your
> skill in the skillset.

[image]

Also, I tried the same using a single file but still the same error.

This same process was working fine earlier but now somehow with the same configuration, it's not working.

Could you please let me know what can be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check those links https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-common-errors-warnings and this https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/39265?

Comment: Yeah, I went through those docs but not much help regarding this error. I tried executing several times but still the same error.